# Case statement for 'where [value] is not null'

Tags: sql, null, case, where-clause

I've seen plenty of SO questions where someone is testing for a NULL value within a case statement, but nothing of the nature of this question. I want the return of the case statement to be a 'is not null' expression for a where clause.

This is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Id) (
     SELECT DISTINCT AId AS Id
     FROM table2 As t2
     INNER JOIN table3
     ON (
     ...
     )
     WHERE CASE
          WHEN test_value <> '' THEN (another_value IS NOT NULL) 
     END
)
```

This gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.

In short, if the test value is not empty-string, then I do not want rows with another_value=NULL in my table1.

My program needs to pass 2 cases

```
Case 1:
Row#     test_value     another_value    ....
1        'tst'          '919'
2        'tst'           NULL
ONLY ROW ONE SHOULD BE INSERTED

Case 2:
Row#     test_value     another_value    ....
1        ''             '919'
2        ''              NULL
BOTH ROWS SHOULD BE INSERTED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE ((isnull(test_value,'') <> '' and ISNULL(another_value,'') <> '') OR ISNULL(test_value,'') = '')
```

Comment: The bottom example works when test_value != '', but fails (filters out everything) when test_value = ''.

Comment: @matrumz, made an update. So basically, if test_value for that row has a value then another_value for that row also must have a value. If test_value for that row does not have a value, the it doesn't matter what value another_value has?

Comment: I'll run this. See updated question for cases and results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
WHERE CASE
        WHEN test_value <> '' AND another_value IS NOT NULL THEN another_value  
      END
```

Comment: Return error: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"